# Missing packages in ros natty repository

Tags: ubuntu-natty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i'm trying to install ros in my ubuntu natty, running in a virtual box, but it appears that there is some missing packages.
I Followed the steps in http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu but when i try to install the package ros-diamondback-desktop-full it just doesn't show. I could only isntall the ros-diamondback-desktop.

Also, when i search for the gazebo stack, i can't find the diamondback one. Here is my output of the command "apt-cache search gazebo":

```
ros-diamondback-pr2-common - PR2 robot description and PR2-specific messages
ros-unstable-cob-simulation - Care-O-bot stack with simulation packages
ros-unstable-pr2-common - PR2 robot description and PR2-specific messages
ros-unstable-simulator-gazebo - Gazebo Simulator
```

i just have no idea why i can't find the packages i want to install u_u

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10618/missing-packages-in-ros-natty-repository/) by [Bruno Normande](https://answers.ros.org/users/560/bruno-normande/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2011-07-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Bruno, can you try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-desktop-full
```

There was an issue with the 32-bit natty debs that may have caused your problem, but I think it should be fixed now

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bruno Normande](https://answers.ros.org/users/560/bruno-normande/) on 2011-07-18**:
It's fine now. ty